# Strange casting behaviour when using performSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I have following code:

```
protocol Greeter {
    func printHi()
}

struct Person: Greeter {
    func printHi() {
        print("hi")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var person: Person?

    @IBAction func tap(_ sender: Any) {
        person = Person()
        perform(with: person!)
    }

    func perform(with greeter: Greeter) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "test", sender: greeter)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let greeter = sender as? Greeter
        let person = sender as? Person
        let greeter2 = sender as? Person as? Greeter

        print("Greeter: \(greeter)")
        print("Person: \(person)")
        print("Greeter2: \(greeter2)")
    }
}
```

and it gives me following output:

```
Greeter: nil
Person: Optional(testSegue.Person())
Greeter2: Optional(testSegue.Person())
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Additional info:

- I don't get any `nil` values if I do the same prints before calling `performSegue`
- the `"test"` segue is a "Show" segue from this ViewController to another
- I have made an example project with this code, which would suggest that it is not related to unclean states or anything similar

**WORKAROUND**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let greeter = sender as? AnyObject as? Greeter

    print("Greeter: \(greeter)")
}
```

Comment: Presumable that the `as? ProtocolType` does not work immediately but only with an intermediary `as? SpecificType as? ProtocolType` !?

Comment: Nothing to do with `performSegue`, and please see also https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871 which contains some excellent minimal reductions in the comments. "It's an issue with a struct value being converted to AnyObject and then to Any." See esp. Hamish's reduction at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871?focusedCommentId=21595&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-21595